# Rails 3 - processing data in other method of other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, data-processing

I have controller with name **AdminController** where i have method **create_school_head**:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create_school_head
    @user = User.new
  end
  ...
end
```

Also i have view **create_school_head**:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :user_login, "Login", :class => "control-label" %>

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :user_login %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :password, "Password", :class => "control-label" %>

        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :password %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
<%  end %>
```

Routes.rb

```
ElSchool::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users,    :only => [ :new, :create, :show ]
  resources :sessions, :only => [ :new, :create, :destroy ]

  get "sessions/new"

  match 'pages/wrong_page', :to => 'pages#wrong_page'
  match '/signin',          :to => 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout',         :to => 'sessions#destroy'

  match '/admins/backups', :controller => 'admins',
                           :action     => 'backups'

  match '/admins/users_of_system', :controller => 'admins',
                                   :action     => 'users_of_system'

  match '/admins/create_school_head', :controller => 'admins',
                                      :action => 'create_school_head'

  match '/admins/create_teacher', :controller => 'admins',
                                  :action => 'create_teacher'

  root :to => 'sessions#new'                                                  #Home
end
```

Right now it pass data to create method of User controller. I would like to send data from this form after buttons submit in other method of **AdminController**, for example in method **process_school_head**. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :url option in your form_for method. Eg.,

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => process_school_head_url, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
```

You need to have this in your route too.

```
match '/admins/process_school_head' => 'admins#process_school_head', :as => :process_school_head
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I created this method in controller and tried to implement your suggestion and now i get: `NameError in Admins#create_school_head. undefined local variable or method process_school_head_url for #<#<Class:0x007fce689db500>:0x007fce68a12230>`

Comment: I was giving an example url. You need to show us what your routes.rb file looks like. Did you set up any special route for that action?

Comment: I added my `routes.rb`, please, check my post again!